# get WebBrowser1 html content after Ajax loaded (vb 2010)

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

hope to see some assistance in question how to obtain full HTML code  from  WebBrowser1 element after AJAX is loaded.

i have a pages with dynamically loaded content and i need to get this content after it's loaded by pressing a button.

also i tried to get div content with dynamic data but did not work(

```
RichTextBox1.Text = WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById(TextBox1.Text).OuterText
```

i.m not able to make HTTPRequest from application due to website complexity (easier to get content from WebBrowser1 )

Comment: The goal of AJAX is to load data after the main page is loaded and update data continuously, time or weather for example. so depending on the page maybe you can't. I know `WebBrowser` has a `WebBrowser.DocumentCompleted` Event but not sure if this will fire after AJAX

Comment: yes you are right.. But i manually wait until page is loaded, all ajax calls are finished and than i want  click a button and get full HTML incl. ajax loaded content

Comment: if you wait until everything is loaded then to get everything just do: `webbrowser.document.body.innerhtml`

Comment: not working.... There is no needed content inside but the content is shown on the page..

Comment: The content you see is the source rendered.... thats how HTML with CSS works..

Comment: Investigated page structure deeper and realized that this are not AJAX calls... document is full of IFRAMEs and the content is loaded into Iframes... So now trying to get it's content..

Comment: thank you google http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?633551-RESOLVED-Getting-HTML-source-Elements-from-Iframe-using-WebBrowser

Answer (score 0):

Investigated page structure deeper and realized that this are not AJAX calls... document is full of IFRAMEs and the content is loaded into Iframes. (((

the way how to obtain IFRAME content

```
RichTextBox1.Text = WebBrowser1.Document.Window.Frames(0).Document.Body.InnerText
```